# How to write more than one Procedure in one query?

Tags: sql-server

```sql
-- Task1

CREATE PROCEDURE Clients_GetAll 
AS
SELECT ClientID, ClientName, Address 
FROM Clients;
GO

EXEC Clients_GetAll;

-- Task2

CREATE PROCEDURE Clients_Insert
@ClientID INT, @ClientName VARCHAR(50),
@Address VARCHAR(100), @Email
VARCHAR(30), @Phone INT, @Business
VARCHAR(30) AS
INSERT INTO Clients (ClientID, ClientName, Address, Email, Phone, Business) 
VALUES (@ClientID, @ClientName, @Address, @Email, @Phone, @Business)
GO
```

I tried using Go but I got an error:

> Procedure Clients_Insert, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 11]
> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Comment: How are you executing the above statements? if you were to dump those into SSMS, they would run fine (assuming Task2 is in a separate connection).

Comment: GO is not a tsql statement. A little trivial searching on that topic will find many discussions.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, @real4you . Are you trying to run the above in MySQL, rather than SQL Server?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio 18 to be more specific

Comment: you need a GO after `EXEC Clients_GetAll;` - it can't be in the same batch as the following `CREATE PROC`

Answer (score 0):

try put the insert in the begin/ end statement?

Example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Clients_Insert @ClientID INT, @ClientName VARCHAR(50), @Address VARCHAR(100), @Email VARCHAR(30), @Phone INT, @Business VARCHAR(30) AS 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Clients (ClientID, ClientName, Address, Email, Phone, Business) VALUES (@ClientID, @ClientName, @Address, @Email, @Phone, @Business)
END
GO
```